# How to customize search box in Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint

Please help me explain this difference.

1. What is the difference of position [search bar] between two tenants?

   - tenant a: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fguPF.png
   - tenant b: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbFUm.png
2. How to setup such position?

Answer (score 0):

They are basically the same.

You can use CSS position to adjust the position of the search box.

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

If you want to add custom CSS to SharePoint Online modern page,you need to upload CSS with SPFX.

https://github.com/hugoabernier/react-application-injectcss